# Por qué el lookbehind negativo (?<! ) no funciona dentro de una estructura de opciones multiples (?: ) como se esperaba en mi patrón regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, string, regex

```py
import re

input_text = "Voy a pasar por el estudio de abogados en el centro de la ciudad."

info_about_speaker_list = [["nombre", ""], ["edad", ""], ["gustos_e_intereses", ""], ["sobre_estudios", ""], ["sobre_trabajo", ""], ["sobre_pareja", ""], ["donde_vive", ""]]

#copia creando una lista auxiliar donde colocaremos las capturas
output_info_about_speaker_list = info_about_speaker_list.copy()

studies_match = re.search(r"(?:soy\s*un\s*estudiante\s*de|estoy\s*estudiando|(?<!al|el|un)\s*estudio)\s+(\w+\s?\w*)", input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
if studies_match: output_info_about_speaker_list[3][1] = studies_match.group(1)

print(output_info_about_speaker_list)
```

Porque captura los datos aunque este colocando la estructura *negative lookbehind* `(?<! )`, en este caso `(?<!al|el|un)`, para evitar que la regex detecte la coincidencia y el grupo de captura `(\w+\s?\w*)` captura la seccion de string

Tienes tres opciones dentro del *non-capturing group* cuya estructura es `(?: ...)`, y luego dentro de una de esas opciones el *negative lookbehind* `(?<!al|el|un)`. La parte del negative lookbehind busca asegurarse de que antes de la palabra "estudio" no aparezcan las palabras "al", "el" o "un".

Este es el output incorrecto en donde ignora la restriccion

```py
[['nombre', ''], ['edad', ''], ['gustos_e_intereses', ''], ['sobre_estudios', 'de abogados'], ['sobre_trabajo', ''], ['sobre_pareja', ''], ['donde_vive', '']]
```

Y asi deberia ser para este ejemplo en donde la restriccion si dee actuar:

```py
[['nombre', ''], ['edad', ''], ['gustos_e_intereses', ''], ['sobre_estudios', ''], ['sobre_trabajo', ''], ['sobre_pareja', ''], ['donde_vive', '']]
```

Este es un experiento simple que hice para probar el codigo, aunque no funciona bien lo cual es extraño porque contradice lo que encontre en la documentacion de las regex, citando `"La estructura (?<! ... ) es una búsqueda negativa que se utiliza para verificar que una determinada expresión regular NO aparece antes de la posición actual en la cadena. No importa si las opciones tienen la misma cantidad de letras o no, el uso de (?<! ... ) debe funcionar correctamente en cualquier caso."`

He intentado colocar un `\b` delante del `(?<! ... )` pero tampoco parece funcionar. ¿Que deberia hacer? ¿O que es lo que no estoy entendiendo en la estructuracion de estas restricciones de coincidencia, por lo que en el contexto de este codigo no funcionan?

Comment: Me parece que tu pregunta no tiene que ver  mucho con Python. Te recomiendo la reformules en términos de Regex, así tienes más personas que puedan atender a tu consulta.

Comment: pero si tiene el tag de regex? tambien el de python para indicar que se trata del motor de regex de python el que uso

Comment: Era solo un concejo que puede o no resultar. Por ejemplo puede haber alguien que sepa la respuesta a tu pregunta (que es netamente de un lookbehind negativo) pero él sabe JAVA, quizás ni pase a visitar tu pregunta porque está en otro lenguaje que no domina. Yo habría preguntado solo con "regex" y habría puesto un ejemplo en javascript ya que es posible ejecutar un snippet directamente con las herramientas del sitio

Comment: Está bien lo que hizo OP @Yussef ([python] + [regex]). De hecho, fijate en la última oración del extracto de la etiqueta [regex].

Comment: @Yussef la intención de tu comentario es muy buena, pero justamente cada lenguaje de programación tiene una implementación diferente en el motor de regex. Especialmente en esta pregunta, la respuesta sería completamente diferente en otro lenguaje. Además, en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info se pide que SIEMPRE se incluya la etiqueta del lenguaje de programación

Comment: @padaleiana Pollo Ok, ok!!! entendí!

Answer (score 0):

En esta expresión

```
(?<!al|el|un)\s*estudio
```

el problema no está en el lookbehind sino en `\s*`.

El motor de regex siempre va a intentar todas las posiciones hasta encontrar una coincidencia. Y si bien fallaría desde acá

```
un estudio
  |
 fallaría
```

perfectamente puede coincidir desde la posición después del espacio

```
un estudio
   |
 coincide
```

porque en esa posición no está precedido por `"un"` y coincide con `\s*estudio` (porque `\s*` también coincide con cero espacios).

- Si no se ve el porqué, hay que tener en cuenta que `"un"` no es lo mismo que `"un "` con un espacio al final

Los lookbehinds están limitados a un largo de texto fijo, y eso los hace muy poco prácticos. Si bien algo como esto puede funcionar:

```
(?<!al|el|un) estudio
```

mi recomendación es que busques una solución alternativa. Por ejemplo, viendo en el código, después de la coincidencia, que no incluya ninguna de las palabras prohibidas.

---

Por otro lado, en el texto que citaste, dice que no importa si las opciones tienen el mismo largo del texto, lo cual puede ser cierto para algunos motores de regex, pero no es válido para `re` en python. Esto podés leerlo en https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html